# How to set Explorer's background wallpaper, while I'm looking at "Computer"?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

How can I set a desired wallpaper in the Explorer background in Windows 7 while looking at the list of drives (aka "Computer").

For example: If press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>, the system shows the list of hard drives; I want to change that white background to a picture.

Comment: What the what?...

Comment: is it possible to change hard drive background?

Comment: What? Change the hard drive background? Where? What is `the hard drive background`?

Comment: if you open any drive, it will display some folders that drive background . how i need to change?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 its not a folder background question,change the white background of list of hard drives

Comment: Your caveat of "without special software" pretty much makes the answer "you can't do it" -- AFAIK.